# BarCode Scanner in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application that needs to capture a barcode Image using Camera of the phone and scan the Barcode of that Application and return us its value.
I have seen an application called ZXing in Internet.I got the corresponding .apk file of that app and also its source.But I am not able to find how to implement that API in my application.Can any one help me in sorting out this issue ? Also I also need information regarding where can I find BarCode Scanner ZXing application documentation.
I will be waiting for reply.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZXing provides two things: a library and an application. You are looking for the library...

And sometimes you should simply read the wiki! http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes

Answer (score 1):

I want to share few bar code scanner in android so that you can go through by link and select perfect scanner according to your project need.

**1. ZXing Library**

Integration:  https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Platform Supported: iOS , Android, Window, OSX

Type : Free

**2. Vision Smart Scanner:**

Integration : http://www.visionsmarts.com/index.html#

Platform Supported: iOS (iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad)   Android (autofocus and fixed focus)

Type : Not Free

**3. Google Vision API:**

Integration : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#5

Platform Supported: iOS , Android (autofocus and fixed focus)

Type : Free

**4. Scandit Scanner:**

Integration : https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/scandit
                 http://www.scandit.com/products/barcode-scanner/

Type : Free

Platform: iOS, Android, Window

**5. Manatee barcode scanner:**

Integration : www.manateeworks.com

Platform: iOS, Swift, MacOSX, Linux, Android, Window, Google Glass, Vuzix

So please select any according to your app.
thanks.